# Importing large dataset into neo4j (with a twist) - slow

Tags: neo4j, cypher, py2neo

I'm working with approx 17mm prescription claims each containing the following fields (subset) :

```
claim_id (one record per claim)
patient_id
drug_id
provider_id
```

My nodes are same as the fields above and the relationships are:

```
patient - [:FILLED] -> prescription
provider - [:WROTE] -> prescription
prescription -[:CONTAINS] -> drug
```

The input file is not ordered, i.e. `patient / provider / drug` can appear at any place in the file.

I'm using py2neo, Cypher `MERGE` and batch size of 1,000 rows to process to ensure that there are no duplicate patients, providers or drugs being created.

`Problem`: Performance - it's taking about a minute per batch (4 nodes + 4 relationships X 1,000) and that time is increasing as the graph is growing.

`Question`: Is there a better way of doing this? Open to non-python suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to do csv + cypher, you can look at the shell-import tools:

https://github.com/jexp/neo4j-shell-tools#cypher-import

there csv columns are mapped to parameters for your cypher statement.

Make sure to create unique constraints / indexes upfront (for 2.0), so you can leverage them during the insert with MERGE

if you want to have a dynamic rel-type you can use #{type} in your statement (which is not resolved by cypher but the import tool)

Check out the CSV batch-importer, that should be able to import your data in a few minutes.

See: https://github.com/jexp/batch-import/tree/20#neo4j-csv-batch-importer

Just create one or more csv files for nodes and for relationships

Comment: Thanks Michael. I saw these. The thing I don't understand here is how to ensure non-duplication of nodes. I.e. if i have a physician 1 on line 1 and create node there + rels, and then physician 1 on line 10, how do I structure the input files for this (same goes for drugs patients and rels)? Apologize in advance if question is naive - only been using neo4j about for a week :)

Answer (score 1):

You could also have a look at using [Geoff](http://nigelsmall.com/geoff) through the [load2neo](http://nigelsmall.com/load2neo) extension. This supports uniqueness through its exclamation mark syntax so might be able to help you out.

The overall syntax looks very similar to Cypher with a few minor differences and py2neo has direct support for load2neo with the [`load_geoff`](http://book.py2neo.org/en/latest/graphs_nodes_relationships/#py2neo.neo4j.GraphDatabaseService.load_geoff) method.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I do for data sets with similar size in Python/py2neo:

Split the creation of unique nodes and relationships. Make sure to use a [WriteBatch](http://book.py2neo.org/en/latest/batches/) to speed up the process.

1. Create all `patient`, `provider`, `drug` nodes and store the py2neo nodes in a Python dict with `patient_id`, `provider_id` or `drug_id` as key. Use dict to make sure each id is only created once.
2. Go over your data again, create `claim` nodes and relationships to uniqe `patient`, `provider`, `drug` nodes. Py2neo allows to create a `claim` node and relationships for this node in the same batch.

   ```
   # write batch
   batch = WriteBatch(graph_db)

   for line in your_data:
       # your fields
       claim_id = ...
       patient_id = ...

       patient_node = my_dict_from_step_one[patient_id]

       claim_node = batch.create({'claim_id': claim_id})
       batch.create(rel(patient_node, "FILLED", claim_node))

   results = batch.submit()
   ```

17 m operations will make your batch explode. Try to submit every 1000 times or so.